# What is the meaning of these two sentences in David Copperfield?

Tags: idioms, figurative, charles-dickens

There are two sentences in *David Copperfield* that I don't quite understand, with regards to their (possible) figurative meaning.

**Chapter XIII:**

> [...] a muslin curtain partly undrawn in the middle, a large round green screen or fan fastened on to the window-sill, a small table, and a great chair, suggested to me that my aunt might be at that moment seated in awful state.

What does "to be seated in awful state" mean?

**Chapter XXXVII:**

> [...] I would sit sometimes of a night, opposite my aunt, thinking how I had frightened Dora that time, and how I could best make my way with a guitar-case through the forest of difficulty, until I used to fancy that my head was turning quite grey.

What does David mean when he says that he imagines his head "turning quite gray"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The phrase *to sit in state* originally referred to the king sitting on his throne and carrying out his official duties, and has been extended metaphorically to encompass a broad range of official and formal situations. I don't know why it's in the passive (i.e., *seated* rather than *sitting*), but [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=seated+in+state%2Csitting+in+state&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cseated%20in%20state%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csitting%20in%20state%3B%2Cc0) shows this isn't uncommon.

The word *awful* is an adjective that applies not just to *state*, but gives the narrator's opinion of the whole scene of his aunt sitting in state.  The strictest grammarians might say that it shouldn't be able to do that because *to sit in state* is an idiom, and adjectives should only modify the word they're applied to, but here it does anyway. In any event, putting an adjective in front of *state* in the phrase *to sit in state* is extremely rare.

For *turning grey*, the explanation is much more straightforward. It is a common belief that worrying turns your hair grey.

Comment: I though that when he said "head" he literally meant the head and not the hair :)

Comment: Should probably add that *awful* is used in the old sense of *awesome*, but +1 for the explanation.